# Cheap way of travelling from Paris to nearby countries?

Tags: trains, france, tips-and-tricks, paris

I am traveling to Paris for a month's time. I would like to visit nearby countries like Luxembourg, Spain, Switzerland etc.

Can you please suggest some cheap travel means?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As per our [help] , you'll notice that asking broad, subjective questions is frowned upon.  What's 'cheap' to you? For some people, that's a flight, for others it's hitchhiking.  Cheap in terms of money, or time?  Are you prepared to hire a car, or do you only want public transport. In its current state I'd expect this question to be put on hold, but editing it would certainly help get it answered well.

Comment: Try **carpooling** with [BlaBlaCar](http://www.blablacar.com/). You will find many rides from Paris to the countries around France. I used this for a Paris-Amsterdam and the round-trip cost me 70€.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a favourbale price for train travel, you have to book early and to be flexible. The [Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com) is providing more information on train travel. Although his trips start in London, nearly all of them transit through Paris.

Otherwise, apart from hitchhiking or ridesharing, the bus is probably your best bet. You can e.g. have a look at [Eurolines](http://www.eurolines.fr) and [iDBUS](http://www.idbus.com), two major operators.

Flying can be interesting too, especially for longer trips such as e.g. Spain. You have some low cost carries operating from Paris or nearby (Easyjet, Vueling, Ryanair, ...). Note that Ryanair is operating from Beauvais, 80 kilometers outside of Paris. But other conventional carries can have competitive prices too. Just check specialized sites, such as [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com) or [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Take the plane with a low cost company like easy jet or ryanair. The West europe part is easy to access and pretty cheap.

You can use website like [enter lastminute.com](http://www.fr.lastminute.com)